# Detect repainted area of screen in java

Tags: java, applet, screenshot, repaint

I am creating an applet which will do something like screen sharing . For that I am using Robot class to capture screen area . I want to capture the dirty / repainted areas after first screen shot. I think RepaintManager manager can be used for that. but i dont know how can I use it. I am a novice so a java code will be helpfull. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/02/debugging_swing.html) custom repaint manager for checking if repaints happen on the EDT to see how it overrides addDirtyRegion.